# Google spanner structs as parameter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-python

When using the spanner python client (but perhaps the problem is more general) it seems impossible to pass structs to the query as a parameter.

Consider following setup:

```
from google.cloud.proto.spanner.v1 import type_pb2
from google.cloud import spanner

spanner_client = spanner.Client()
instance = spanner_client.instance('myinstance')
database = instance.database('mydb')
```

If I want to translate following query into using paramaters

```
select * from UNNEST(ARRAY[STRUCT<foo INT64, bar INT64>(1, 2)])
```

By doing

```
STRUCT_TYPE = type_pb2.StructType()
FOO = type_pb2.StructType.Field(name='foo', type=type_pb2.Type(code=type_pb2.INT64))
BAR = type_pb2.StructType.Field(name='bar', type=type_pb2.Type(code=type_pb2.INT64))

STRUCT_TYPE.fields.extend([FOO, BAR])

database.execute_sql('select * from UNNEST(ARRAY[@struct])', 
    params={'struct': [1,2]}, 
    param_types={'struct': STRUCT_TYPE})
```

Would give me

```
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected Type got StructType.
```

Is there any way to allow passing of structs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass structs right now. This is something we're addressing but no firm timeline.